# 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://mathoverflow.net/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 4):

The results have been finalised.

You can see the results at the following post: [Congratulations to our new moderator!](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5472/congratulations-to-our-new-moderator)

Given the number of nominations (2), there was in the end no primary phase.

And, well, I'm it.