# 2022 Election results: Congratulations to our new moderator!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The [election](https://mathoverflow.net/election/3) is over, the [votes have been counted](https://www.opavote.com/results/6571069153476608), and on behalf of the current team and board, I'd like to welcome [David Roberts](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4177/david-roberts) to the [moderators team](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=moderators)!

[image: profile for David Roberts at MathOverflow, Q&A for professional mathematicians]

I'd like to thank [Carl-Fredrik Nyberg-Brodda](https://mathoverflow.net/users/120914/carl-fredrik-nyberg-brodda) and to everyone who participated in this election, one way or another!

Comment: Congratulations, David!

Comment: Thank you both :-)

Comment: Thanks to both Carl-Fredrik and David for putting themselves forwards :)

Comment: Thanks to all for a successful election, and welcome, David, to another phase of life on MathOverflow!

Comment: @Tim I hope I don't regret it :-)

Comment: "votes have been counted": this points to a .blt file. Well, I could open it online (https://filext.com/online-file-viewer.html) and eventually this is just a plain text file, with a list of sequences (such as "1 2 0"...) and the numbered names of candidates at the end. Is there a legend/explanation anywhere to decipher the meaning of the information in the file?

Comment: @YCor: Yes, good point. When I posted this, there was no online count available, but there is now. I'll update the link.

Comment: Congratulations also from me!